# Is it better to ask one complex question or a bunch of tiny questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

I don't want to annoy people. I also don't want others to do my work for me, but my programming skills are completely self taught, as are my math skills, so there are some missing pieces in my knowledge.

So if I ask one question, then when it is answered, ask the next question, is that considered more appropriate or less appropriate than asking it all in one question?

Comment: Similar except in my case, each question IS dependent on the previous questions answer.

Comment: No, the same. If you have two questions, post two questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So if I ask one question, then when it is answered, ask the next question, is that considered more appropriate or less appropriate than asking it all in one question?

Actually, that is the preferred SO way. Ask each in turn as one atomic question. If you need the previous answer to go forward, then put that at the top like this:

> Related: `<previous question link>`

So that people can get the backstory on each step as it builds up. You could even put a separate "Related" at the bottom of a previous Q pointing to the next one in sequence, but don't abuse that too much.