# An ideal SE site for academic researchers on the scale of google scholar

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

There are so many research papers out there. Each is uniquely identified by a DOI handle. When a researcher goes through a paper he may get stuck on understanding some math equation or is confused about the author's philosophical or moral leanings. Rather than him/her going to the relevant SE site and citing the paper and asking the question why can there not be an SE site called Academia SE where he/she just opens a new question linked to the doi handle of the paper.

This way if one person has 100 doubts in a paper he/she does not have to painfully ask 100 separate new questions. Similarly if a person has a doubt in the paper that has already been asked and answered correctly in one of the sites, he will only have to enter the doi handle in the Academia SE site and he/she will get all the past queries regarding that paper.

Researchers all over the world will get so empowered. Is there any site that does this already?

Comment: Yes even i agree that each time only 1 q.p.q. must be asked but it should be linked to a doi handle so that there is a classification layer working in background. So if a person has 100 questions he has to open 100 new questions but do the extra effort to link it to a doi handle which can then later be searched by other researchers painlessly. meaning replace tags with doi handle or supplement it.

Answer (score 9):

I think your proposal may be missing the point of focused Q&A.

I see asking only one question per question as being the essence of focused Q&A and focused Q&A is what sets SE apart from other Q&A sites: [When to ask multiple questions in a single post ? (Revisited)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257391/215590).

Far from being painful it is what enables us to get/find/provide answers instant-like.

Consequently, I cannot see your proposal, at least as currently described, being helpful to the goals of the SE network.

It may be better for you to discuss DOI at [Academia Meta](https://Meta.academia.stackexchange.com) like this user did: [Should top Stack Exchange Academia threads get DOIs and be permanently archived?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1936/8686)