# How to handle questions that tries to cover a topic rather than asking a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I just saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033137/parallel-programming-i-need-some-clarifications#comment28125468_19033137) with 5 question marks in it.

The user asked so many questions, that it was even difficult for him to decide about non-vague title: *"parallel programming - I need some clarifications"*

As far as i know, this isn't the best known method, at least according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) post.

Per my understanding, even if each question is individually good question, the post
isn't.

So why does this post seems to get positive feedback rather than a request to split this to several questions or to be more focused with the question?

Comment: What's wrong with "too broad" close reason? On Drupal I do this, and comment "please ask each question separately", and nobody complained so far.

Comment: The question isn't _that_ broad, it can be (and was) answered in a handful of sentences...

Comment: @Yannis in case when it isn't really too broad, I don't see a reason to handle them in any way, really. But my comment was general as there is no [meta-tag:specific-question] tag on this meta question.

Comment: @Mołot Sure, I wasn't really responding to your comment, I was more commenting on Yosi's suggestion to split the question in question to several questions.

Comment: @Yannis - Thanks, please see my comment to the answer below.

Comment: That example is mostly just a bad title, not a bad question.  It just needs a more specific title to avoid that confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The OP demonstrates prior knowledge of the topic being asked about, and brings that knowledge to the question, asking for specific clarifications.  The question is interesting to the experts, because it exercises their expert domain knowledge.

In addition, it's got decent grammar and punctuation, and is asked in a general enough way to be useful to others who come across the question.  What's not to like?

That's more than you'll get from 90% of the questions that are asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [programmers.se] is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.

Comment: @hjpotter92 [Heh, I'm pretty sure Robert knows that...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)

Comment: @Yannis Yeah! But if the question for professional (expert) developers; shouldn't it be off-topic for [SO]? I understand the point(s) Robert is mentioning in this post and it is perfectly fine by me that the question remain on [so]. But I'd still have to agree with OP here. The 3rd question, in my opinion, is still primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Are you implying that Stack Overflow is just for amateurs?  Hmm, that would explain a few things.

Comment: What I'd like to imply here is that there is a negligible difference b/w [so] and [programmers.se] currently. There are [several questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+async+OR+await+is%3Aq) on Programmers, which, when combined, can sufficiently answer the question in context. Since I haven't had much experience in [tag:C#], I can not go further into detail. If I am wrong, please tell me so, and I'd go back to the novels. :)

Comment: Post that asks three very focused questions isn't too broad in my opinion, i don't see point in splitting since it was answered in handful of sentences (as mentioned). So i guess the main thing i take from here is that a post can contain several questions if they are related and focused? Thanks