# Should questions asking about "how is X done" for 2 unrelated languages be closed/edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-close

What, if anything, should be done with questions asking how to do something in unrelated languages?

Case in point - [Is there a built-in function that comma-separates a number in C, C++, or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479485/is-there-a-built-in-function-that-comma-separates-a-number-in-c-c-or-javascr)

I personally feel that this is similar to 2-in-1 questions, which is covered by [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

So, should they be closed (and for what reason), or should they be edited (and how), or are they fine (and should be left as-is)?

And what should be done about that particular question?

Comment: Two?  That's 3-in-1.

Comment: Well, to be fair, a lot of people say C/C++ when they just mean C++.

Answer (score 1):

There's no **minimal understanding** close reason but there's **lack of information to diagnose a problem** so feel free to use it.

Such questions obviously lack the information to diagnose the problem, because they don't ask what OP wants to achieve, and instead are pointing out, that there's something in other language. It it a problem for Java developer that there is some function in C++? Of course not. Neither is it important for other Java users.

Constructive questions concentrate on the features of the given language, and not on finding the way for automatic code translation.

Comment: However, someone might be undecided on whether he will use one language or the other to achieve a specific purpose and asks the question so that he can make this decision. If javascript has it, he is going to use javascript if C++ has it, C++ and so on. Why close such a question?

Comment: @ThunderGr How to do X is a legitimate question in my opinion, the problem is that it's asked for unrelated languages, so you'll some answer about C++, another about JavaScript, and which one should be accepted over the other? It's actually a subset of asking 2-in-1 questions, which is covered in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: @satuon The OP refers to the type:"Is there X in Y,Z,N language?". So, suppose that someone asks "Is there a build in function that sorts an array in C++, Javascript or Python?". You see that this person has a selection of languages he is able to use, but he needs this bit of information to decide which one. Splitting this question is redundant, while closing it does not seem appropriate because, in my opinion, this is a legitimate question and the answer can help other people with their choices.

Comment: `Such questions obviously lack the information to diagnose the problem, because they don't ask what OP wants to achieve` -- The comma question is perfectly clear about what the OP wants to achieve.