# Trouble expressing a question and whether or not it's multiple questions

Tags: support, questions

Basically I want to know how your GPU renders frames in certain circumstances

1. GPU can output frames faster than your monitor can display them
2. GPU is capped at a certain frame rate
3. GPU is throttling itself

I'd go into more detail about what I mean in each scenario in the question.

I guess for the question title I'd go with

#### "How does a GPU render frames in different throttling/capping circumstances?"

but that seems like a mouthful and isn't very clear.

And then I think it sort of counts as 1 question just with multiple scenarios?

I plan to ask on superuser.com

Different from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) as they aren't different questions in the same area.

Comment: You may also find more specific guidance and help forming your question by asking on [SU's meta site](https://meta.superuser.com/) directly, if that's where you plan on asking.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it’s fine, because the points are pretty closely related to one another and one answer may well cover your bases.

But if you're overly specific in your details for each part of the question, then you might run into issues if less than all of your questions are answerable.

Comment: I agree with this, but will say it is site-dependent. Many sites allow multi-barrelled questions if they all flow naturally from the first one and especially if answering the first requires answering later ones first or they really are a single question in multiple parts. For example, "What is the sum of the following series? Does it even converge?" is a single question with a clarifying sub-question. "How do I get to New York City from Providence? What time does the New York Public Library Main Branch open?" is two questions.